# Auto-completion for `org-sparse-tree` and `org-match-sparse-tree`

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am learning tags in Emacs `org-mode`, but I found when using `C-c / m` (aka `org-sparse-tree` -- *Show entries selected by a tags/property match*) or `C-c \` (aka `org-match-sparse-tree`) to search tag in a buffer, `TAB` does NOT give auto-completion. In many other cases in `org-mode`, `TAB` always does the job but not here. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Auto-completion of tags (using the `tab` key) works well for me, so there is something else in your setup that is causing the problem.

Comment: Common problems when initially setting up `org-mode` include, but are not limited to, properly configuring the `org-agenda-files` variable.  A user may have more than one file, so that variable can either be a string containing one file or a list of multiple files -- the list has a different format than a string.  There is also a non-interactive function with the same name, which looks up the configuration.  Try the following, which uses the *function* to look-up your configuration and post the results please:  `M-x eval-expression RET (org-agenda-files) RET`

Comment: So that you can see where I am going with this, the chain begins with `org-match-sparse-tree`, which in turn calls `org-scan-tags` using `org-make-tags-matcher`, which uses `org-global-tags-completion-table`, which uses the **function** `org-agenda-files`, which uses the **variable** `org-agenda-files`.  So, if your *variable* `org-agenda-files` is not set up correctly, you are going to have problems with auto-completion of tags.  Note, the *variable* `org-agenda-files` can also point to a directory:  http://superuser.com/a/702079/206164

Comment: In addition, also check to see whether your `org-tag-alist` variable is configured correctly:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-tags.html

Comment: Thanks law list. After I set up the `org-agenda-files`, the autocompletion works, and it only gives the candidate tag names from members of `org-agenda-files`. I thought autocompletion would work within the buffer, even though the agenda files were not set. But it seems that that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I set up the `org-agenda-files`, the autocompletion works, and it only gives the candidate tag names from members of `org-agenda-files`. I thought autocompletion would work within the buffer, even though the agenda files were not set. But it seems that that is not the case.

Comment: If you include additional tags in your `org-tag-alist`, you will also see those tags as potential auto-completions.