# Emacs org-mode tags not found

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm learning to use emacs and org-mode. I create a few tags, in a `.org` file, as such `:outline:` lets say.
And then searched for them using:

```
C-c a m outline
C-c a t outline
C-c \   outline
```

And the output is always (basically, did't find anything):

```
Headlines with TAGS match: outline
Press `C-u r' to search again with new search string
```

What am I doing wrong. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened to my previous comment, but it *mysteriously* disappeared.  Here is a link to a related thread where a new Emacs user had not properly configured the variables `org-agenda-files` and the `org-tag-alist`.  You probably have the same problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/24571109/2112489

Comment: if you want to, add you answer as an "full" answer below so that I can vote you up.
in any case thanks a lot lawlist!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common problems when initially setting up `org-mode` include, but are not limited to, properly configuring the `org-agenda-files` variable.  A user may choose to have one or more files, or a directory.

Here is an example of multiple files:

```
(setq org-agenda-files 
  (list "~/org/gtd.org" "~/org/work.org" "~/org/personal.org"))
```

Here is an example of a directory:

```
(setq org-agenda-files (list "~/"))

(setq org-agenda-file-regexp "\\`[^.].*\\.org\\|.todo\\'")
```

It is interesting to note that there is also non-interactive *function* with the same name, which looks up the configuration of the `org-agenda-files` *variable* -- the *function* is what `org-mode` generally relies upon when any other function looks up the value of the *variable*.  To see an example of how that non-interactive *function* works, the user can do something like this:

```
M-x eval-expression RET (org-agenda-files) RET
```

The importance of setting the `org-agenda-files` variable can be seen by examining the function `org-match-sparse-tree`, which in turn calls `org-scan-tags` using `org-make-tags-matcher`, which uses `org-global-tags-completion-table`, which uses the function `org-agenda-files`, which uses the variable `org-agenda-files`.  If the variable `org-agenda-files` is not set up correctly, a tags search and auto-completion of tags will not work correctly.

Another common issue arises when the variable `org-tag-alist` has not yet been properly set up -- here is a link to the manual page on that issue:   http://www.orgmode.org/manual/Setting-tags.html

Comment: The only thing that bothers me is that the command `C-c \ ` still doesnt work. I mean I get the prompt "Match:" at the bottom, but it doesnt do the actual match. 
I think that there's something misconfigured. Also it impeeds org-mode from interpreting this: `#+TODO: TODO FEEDBACK VERIFY | DONE CANCELED` correctly.

Comment: When things are not working correctly and there is no useful error message to point you in the right direction -- `(setq debug-on-error t)` -- it usually pays off by starting with a minimal configuration to run some preliminary tests.  Once you get that working, then slowly add the rest of your configuration until you find the culprit.  For example, start with one of the examples in the answer above and the debug setting, and nothing else in your configuration (e.g., `.emacs` file) -- the test file buffer should be a file that is defined within `org-agenda-files`.  Then try out your match.

Comment: You should also be using a recent org-version to run your tests -- e.g., 8 point something. I'm running 8.2.6 at the present time.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the OP and I'm baffled at the complexity of the answer, for commands that you go through in the beginners' tutorial for org-mode...